# Selecting limits of volume integral when the limits are dependent on another variable.

Tags: integration, limits

Evaluate $\int\int\int_v (2x+y)dV$ where V is the closed region bounded by the parabolic cylinder $z=4-x^2$ and the planes x=0,y=0,y=2 and z=0.

I computed the integral to get a final answer of $-\frac{80}{3}$ but the expected answer is $\frac{80}{3}$.Here's what I did:

$\int\int\int_v (2x+y)dV$

$=\int_0^2\int_{4-x^2}^0\int_0^2 (2x+y) dy dz dx$

$=\int_0^2\int_{4-x^2}^0 [(2xy+\frac{y^2}{2})]_0^2 dz dx$

$=\int_0^2\int_{4-x^2}^0 (4x+2) dz dx$

$=\int_0^2 [4xz+2z]_{4-x^2}^0 dx$

$=\int_0^2 {-4x(4-x^2)-2(4-x^2)} dx$

$=\int_0^2 {4x(x^2-4)+2(x^2-4)} dx$

$=-\frac{80}{3}$

I have a feeling I did something wrong with the limits and probably those of z. But since the parabolic cylinder is closed ABOVE by z=0,shouldn't the limits I chose be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the region $V$ is above the plane $z=0$:
$$x\in[0,2] \implies z=4-x^2\ge 0.$$
Thus, the limits for $z$ are from $0$ to $4-x^2$ and not otherwise:
$$\int_0^2\int_0^{4-x^2}\int_0^2 (2x+y) dy dz dx.$$

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! Silly me!